# Scala actors smart routing

Tags: multithreading, scala, actor, akka

I need to execute some (let's say 10) tasks with less (i.e.) 3 actors.

But I don't want to distribute all the tasks in the beginning, because time of execution may vary. That's why I need to send all of them 1 task and when any finishes he'll be given a new task. This way when first task takes 3 seconds and rest only ~ 0.5s job can be done in 3 sec.

Having 10 tasks list:

```
(() => Thread.sleep(3000); println("done long"}) :: (1..9).map({() => println("done short")})
```

I want to have output:

```
done short
done short
done short
done short
done short
done short
done short
done short
done short
done long
```

I could write the manager actor, returning actors to manager and redistributing the work again, but I was hoping to find a fixed solution in Scala or Akka.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Akka supports Dispatchers and in particular work stealing. Look [this](http://blog.vasilrem.com/flexible-load-balancing-with-akka-in-scala) post for the details.

Comment: Thanks! 'Work stealing' was the phrase to look for :-) Another article here: http://janvanbesien.blogspot.com/2010/03/load-balancing-actors-with-work.html